# Popup which persists through page redirect Next.js (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js, popup

I am using Next.js for one of the projects that I work on. I wonder if someone could help me with an advice on how to show a popup (popup component, I think it could be based on Alert or Modal or something) to user in browser when I redirect to a certain page. In my very case, I am implementing a password reset logic and on the page for setting new password I am verifying the token in the url. If that token is not valid I have an immediate redirect to login. I just want to give the user some general message like "Not successful" or something to indicate that reset did not work. This should be done as a popup in my opinion and should be shown for some seconds on login page that we land our user on.

Thank you in advance and wish you all good!

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I like to just add a query to the url of the login page like `?error=password-reset-failed` and then create the popup based on that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I indeed did it this way which I find convenient for my case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) for notification

For example with @ernesto comment, my logic like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
if (query === 'error') {
toast.error('Not successful')
}
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did'nt know react-toastifym but I find it really cool. Now combined with @ernesto suggestion and toastify it looks very good! :)